# Is admin consent required in a native app using Directory.AccessAsUser.All?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

According to [this page](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2473127&seqNum=2), admin consent should not be required for a native app using Directory.AccessAsUser.All

> As a side note, for native applications, this permission behaves like a User permission instead. A native app does not have an identity per se, and it is already doing the direct user’s bidding anyway. It stands to reason that the app should be able to do what the user is able to do, just as happens on-premises when a classic native client (say Word or Excel) can or cannot open a document from a network share depending on whether the user has the correct permissions on that folder.

I'm not seeing this in practice. The "API Permissions" page in Azure portal warns me that admin consent will be required, and users attempting to sign in using my app also get told that admin consent is required.

I haven't provided a Web redirect URL, just checked https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient under the Public Clients section - i'd expect this to be enough for admin consent not to be required, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Is the doc above wrong, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That page is wrong, consent framework doesn't allow a permission to be Admin/User.
If it is marked Admin, it requires admin consent.

That may have been right in the past though.